# Spark SQL: convert milliseconds timestamp in JSON format to dateformat

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Schema has the dataType declared as `Timestamp` but spark job is not converting it in the right format.

```
Dataset<Row> stream = sparkSession.readStream()
          .format("kafka")
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootstrapServersString)
          .option("subscribe", topic)
//          .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 10000)
          .load();

      Dataset<Row> rawStream = stream
              .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
              .select(from_json(col("value"), eventSpecificStructType).as("eventData"))
              .select("eventData.*")
              .filter(col("eventType").equalTo("Test"));
```

Timestamp coming in as `1542126896113` gets converted to `50838-01-28 18:49:111.0`.
Is there a way to cast milliseconds to datetime format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create a UDF in Java.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("....Date time pattern...");
spark.udf().register("timestamp", new UDF1<String, Timestamp>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1335972766810808134L;
    @Override
    public Timestamp call(String source)
    {
      try{
            return new Timestamp(dateFormat.parse(source).getTime());
         } catch (ParseException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
      return null;
     }
 }, DataTypes.TimestampType);
```

Finally:

```
stream = stream.withColumn("col", callUDF("timestamp", dataframe.col("col")));
```

Answer (score -1):

How about dividing the millisecond value by 1000. Is below meets your expectation?

```
val df = Seq(("1542126896113"),("1542126896116")).toDF("unixtime")
  df.withColumn("times",from_unixtime('unixtime.cast("long")/1000)).show(false)
```

Output

```
+-------------+-------------------+
|unixtime     |times              |
+-------------+-------------------+
|1542126896113|2018-11-13 22:04:56|
|1542126896116|2018-11-13 22:04:56|
+-------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. Saw a couple of examples in python and spark. I am looking for the syntax in Java.